# setNavigationBarHidden not working programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to programmatically create different view controllers, where the first should not show the navbar, however the second should. I can't seem to do anything to get the second view controller to show the navbar. All the code compiles fine and the button which pushes the controller works, because the second screen turns green as it should.

Here is the AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let startupScreenController = StartupScreenController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: startupScreenController)

    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    return true
}
```

Here is the first View Controller:

```
func skipButtonPressed() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

Here is the second View Controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the Navigation Bar on this view controller

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 24/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1  )
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like below.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: don't forget to add call `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: You're welcome..... :) you should accept correct answer as per stackoverflow guideline so that other people can get help having same issue! @unicorn_surprise

Comment: this wouldn't compile as `animated` is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

For my project it only worked when I added it in viewWillLayoutSubviews().

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hide the `navigation bar` in a following way. Set `false` to enable back

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Directly you can use to that navigation bar code in ViewDidLoad.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: 
   animated)
   }
```