# Navigation bar not appearing when pushing a controller from a presented ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios16

I have following code to present a `UIViewController` (named A) with UINavigationController.
I have kept navigation bar hidden as I do not want it on A by using following code

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

but when I push `UIViewController` named B I want the navigation bar to be displayed but it's not working even If set

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

on `UIViewController` B. Can someone help me in this?

Here is the code to present `UIViewController` A

```
AppDelegate* delegate = [AppDelegate applicationDelegate];
    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_MAIN bundle:nil];
    SelectionViewController *tutorial = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectionViewController"];
    tutorial.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    tutorial.definesPresentationContext = YES;
        [tutorial setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    tutorial.delegate = self;
    
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tutorial];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [navController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    navController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    navController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
        [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    [delegate.tabBarController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Here is the code to push `UIViewController` B

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AppDetail" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

**Additional information**
UIViewController A is in different storyboard and B is in different
A's code is written in OBJ-C and B's code is in swift.

Comment: Instead of unhiding the navigationbar immediately after pushing the viewcontroller, can you try doing the same in `viewDidLoad of ViewController 2` can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072346/setnavigationbarhidden-not-working-programmatically)

Comment: @vignesh Now I am getting the issue again. I just presented another ViewController from SelectionViewController but I'm not able to see navigation bar. I have tried all the things but no luck

Comment: Have you tried switching the way you are unhiding the navigationbar and presnting? ex: `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];` Basically unhide first and then present. Does unhiding navigation bar from viewdidload in new controller not working? If you can share what are the options you have tried it would be easy to figureout.

Comment: I have already tried what you've suggested. I solved it by adding another UINavigationController and for now it solved the problem